# Twython Api: IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read, 1 more expected)

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-streaming-api, twython

I am trying to use Twython Streaming API and I am getting the following error after some amount of time (arround 220+ tweets consumed)

Here is the stacktrace where error happens. I have seen recommendations to upgrade requests library - but it's already updated.

```
chunk = self.fp.read(min(amt, MAXAMOUNT))
if not chunk:
   raise IncompleteRead(''.join(s), amt)
s.append(chunk)
amt -= len(chunk)

IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read, 1 more expected)

count 214
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and reading the thread on GitHub about it, https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/issues/288, the suggested solution was to wrap the tracker with a try/catwhile True:  #Endless loop: personalize to suit your own purposes

```
try: 
    stream.statuses.filter(track='foo bar,foobar,more search strings here')
except:
    #e = sys.exc_info()[0]  #Get exception info (optional)
    #print 'ERROR:',e  #Print exception info (optional)
    continue
```

I've implemented it in my use of Twython and so far, while the error has occurred once or twice since (from apparently either a Twitter fault, or network errors), it restarts and continues gracefully.